# Macro code to delete rows that were not pasted over during a macro copy & paste action

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I am trying to write a macro code where it deletes all the rows at the bottom which where not pasted over during a copy paste.

I have a list of sites that today have a count of 200 and tomorrow 180.

When my macro does a copy paste and it was 200 yesterday and 180 today I want it to automatically recognize that the 20 rows at the bottoms need to be deleted since they were not pasted over.

Is there a way to do this?

Right now I have this but it deletes only the last 3 sites

```
ActiveCell.Offset(8581, 0).Rows("1:3").EntireRow.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring that the magical number 8581 is somehow determined during the copy operation.

```
dim n as long

n = 8581
ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0).Resize(rows.count - n - activecell.row, 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: yes but that 8581 number is not a constant. it changes

Comment: So change *n* to the new value.

Comment: Perhaps `n = selection.rows.count` will return the correct number of rows freshly pasted.

Comment: Awesome, i will give it a try. Thank you